# Directional pattern in normalized LiDAR point cloud

Tags: r, lidar, las, lidr

I have used the `lidR` package (https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR) to produce a normalized point cloud. I then filter out the points tagged with the overlap bit using:

```
opt_filter(ctg) <- "-drop_overlap"
catalog_retile(ctg)
```

The resulting point cloud appears to have a directional pattern, where points are present in somewhat uniform strips. It seems the unfiltered point cloud has a similar pattern but much it is much less pronounced. Is this a normal feature of lidar data?

Here is a 3d representation of the normalized and filtered point cloud with the pattern I have described: 
[image]

Comment: Now I know that your dataset is sample with two beam this image makes even more sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ALS data are usually sampled with an oscillating mirror carried on a moving platform. The point pattern is thus a zigzag. Here you only have a very tiny region of the flightline so you are seeing near parallel lines. Everything looks ok to me. I'm only questioning the relevance of using `-drop_overlap` because its meaning is often misunderstood

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The area is indeed quite small - it is a ~1000 square meter circle. I'm using `-drop_overlap` to achieve a single coverage point cloud. I will be extracting statistical moments (e.g. 90th percentile height...) from the point clouds to be used as predictor variables in an Above Ground Biomass model. I don't want the distribution of returns to be influenced by double coverage in areas of overlap.

Comment: You are assuming that the `overlap` bit tags the points in overlaps. I might be true... or not. Just sayin'

Comment: You are suggesting that the flag could have been inappropriately set by the data producer. The metadata associated with the las tiles includes the following information 

- *"Swath overage points were identified in these files using the standard LAS overlap bit."* 

- *"the nominal swath overlap, as a Percentage: 20"*

I feel like I should go by what is indicated in the xml metadata...

Comment: If it is documented by the provider it is ok!